# ASP MVC color string in Html.Raw

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to compare two string. Is there existing diffrences in each `index`, i want to color that specific `char` in red (if not match) or green (if it match).

```
            <li>
                @for (int i = 0; i < item.AnswersList.Count; i++)
                {
                    var answerArray = item.AnswersList[i].Output.ToArray();
                    var outputArray = item.OutputList[i].Output.ToArray();

                    for (int j = 0; j < answerArray.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (answerArray[j] == outputArray[j])
                        {
                            @Html.Raw( How to print colorful char here?);
                        }
                    }
                }
            </li>
```

That colored `string` need to be in one line in `<li>` tag.

**EDIT:**

I made this edit to my code:

```
<div style="color: green;">
     @Html.Raw(outputArray[j])
</div>
```

But i get output like that:

[image]

How to make it one word in `<li>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<li style="display: flex;>
   @for (int i = 0; i < item.AnswersList.Count; i++)
   {
      var answerArray = item.AnswersList[i].Output.ToArray();
      var outputArray = item.OutputList[i].Output.ToArray();

      for (int j = 0; j < answerArray.Length; i++)
      {
         if (answerArray[j] == outputArray[j])
         {
            <span style="color: green;">
              ...
            </span>
         }
      }
   }
</li>
```

Comment: But it will print every char in another `<li>` tag. i want to have string in one `<li>` tag with each char coloured

Comment: Sure, it works nice, but <span> gives me whitespace for each character. Could My arrays have whitespaces, strings etc so `span` is unacceptable because each span gives me whitespace between

Comment: if span is giving you extra margin or padding, adapt your css rules. Div containers are block types, while spans are displayed inline. The styling is up to you. Fire up the dev console, find the rule, that is adding the behaviour and adapt or override ut.

Comment: I can pack this `for` in div, but how `css` to no whitespaces between spans will look like?

Comment: I have edited my answer with `<li style="display: flex;">`

Comment: Works great, thanks! Do you know, why `@Html.Raw(chararray[i])` didnt print whitespaces? Whitespaces exist in that array

Comment: It´s because of `display: flex;`. I think the whitespaces are printed out, but removed afterwards.. but how it exactly removes the whitespaces im not sure.. This is an interesting article about the issue: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 1):

I hope you need this:

```
       <li>
            @for (int i = 0; i < item.AnswersList.Count; i++)
            {
                var answerArray = item.AnswersList[i].Output.ToArray();
                var outputArray = item.OutputList[i].Output.ToArray();

                for (int j = 0; j < answerArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    bool isMatch = answerArray[j] == outputArray[j];
                    <div style="color: @(isMatch ? "green" : "red");">
                        @Html.Raw(outputArray[j])
                    </div>
                }
            }
        </li>
```

**UPD**: If you need all chars in one row then use `span` instead of `div`.

**UPD2:** Try this(span but without new line):

```
<span style="color: @(isMatch ? "green" : "red");margin:0;padding:0">@Html.Raw(outputArray[j])</span>
```

Comment: `span` gives me extra whitespace betwean each `span`. In my `char array` i have words, spaces etc. Span makes space foreach char. How to deal with that?

Comment: One way to handle is to add css styling for your divs: `ul>li>div: display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 1):

This should work perfectly. It's just a matter of making sure you don't leave any whitespace around your `<span>` tags, like this:

```
<li>
    @for (int i = 0; i < item.AnswersList.Count; i++)
    {
        var answerArray = item.AnswersList[i].Output.ToArray();
        var outputArray = item.OutputList[i].Output.ToArray();

        for (int j = 0; j < answerArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (answerArray[j] == outputArray[j])
            {<span style="color:green">@Html.Raw(outputArray[j])</span>}
            else
            {<span style="color:red">@Html.Raw(outputArray[j])</span>}
        }
    }
</li>
```